# Does callee knows the caller?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a Java utility package, which can be used by multiple services(written in Java) for performing some utility tasks.

Lets say the Java utility package name is U and one of the Service be S. Now S calls a function F of U.

My question is, whether there is a way where function F of package U is able to determine which service S has called it ?
There can be multiple services S1, S2, ... , Sn calling F. I need to know upon a call, which Service Sx is calling that particular F.

Comment: There's not any good way.  It sounds like you ought to be passing specific information to `F` about who's calling it.

Comment: Why would the utility class need to know which client class is calling it? How would the utility class alter its behaviour to suit the different client types?

Comment: see if you can use any method parameters of F and manipulate it. set the service name or some code value in any of method parameters (if possible)where the method is called from the service.

Comment: If some behaviour depends on whether the calling type is `S1` or `S2`, this behaviour should **absolutely** be in the classes `S1` and `S2` themselves, not `U`. Have this behaviour be in an interface `I` that `S1`, `S2`, etc. implement, have `U.F()` accept a parameter of type `I`, have `S1` etc. pass `this` to that parameter...

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem to me: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Why does `U` need to know about `S1, S2...` at all? A utility class should not be aware of all of the (potentially any) objects calling its methods unless under some specific scenario. I am certain there are much more feasible and stable solutions. As some have suggested, the simplest is to have callers of `F` pass themselves as an argument to the method.

Comment: This is called 'state orientation'. It was decided in the 1960s that it's a bad idea for the callee to behave differently depending on who called it. Its behaviour should only depend on its parameter values and the state that's visible to it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like the following requiring you only to create a function `findServiceContainingClass` mapping class names to services (or null):

```
void callee() {
    StackTraceElement[] st = new RuntimeException().getStackTrace();
    for (int i = 1; i < st.length; i++) {
        Service service = findServiceContainingClass(st[i].getClassName());
        if (service != null) break;
    }
    // ... use service
}
```

However it is deemed bad practice to make code behave differently depending on the caller. I would use such code only as a last resort. (It would be okay to use it in a breakpoint condition during debugging. Maybe that is what you intend.)

Answer (score 2):

Object Oriented programming in Java states that your service is scope for invocation, nothing else (forget `static`). So there is no normal way to find who is calling instance's method other than passing `S` instance as argument.

But that does not mean it is impossible.

**If you only need to know what is the type of caller**, you can use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`:

```
StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
StackTraceElement caller = elements[elements.length - 2];
printLn(caller.getClassName());
```

As I said at the beginning it is totally counter objective Java code.

**If you need to refer exact instance**, you probably should add caller as call parameter. I assume that if you want to refer to caller, callee's code is written by you, so you are able to do it. ***As for me it would be best choice, because if you need caller in scope of callee, you should pass it directly.*** Other option is to set caller on ThreadLocal in `U`, but you don't have confidence that developer will do it each time.

**If interface cannot be changed, and U is an interface**, you could create `U` builder object:

```
public class UBuilder {
  public U getS(final S caller) {
    Proxy.newProxyInstance(getClass().getClassLoader(), U.class, 
                           new InvocationHandler() {
      public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, 
                           Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        // store caller value on some ThreadLocal variable
        try {
          method.invoke(proxy, args);
        } finally {
          // remove caller from ThreadLocal variable
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After that you have additional invocation context (`ThreadLocal`) referring `S` instance.

**If `U` is not interface**, `Javassist`, `CgLib` or something similar would help, but only if invoked method is not static or final.

**If `F` is static or final** I see only dramatically hackish answers. Maybe creating own interface imitating `U`, and forwarding method invocations in `InvocationHandler` could be some way. Of course S should refer to this interface, not `U` directly.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If there needs to be some service-specific code that is executed by that utility method, I would declare an interface in the utility class and have the services pass in an instance of it to the method.

Here is a contrived example:

```
public class Utility {

    public interface UtilityInterface {

        public void specificBehavior( Object arg );
    }

    public void utilityMethodF( UtilityInterface utilityInterface, Object... args ) {

        // perform work with args or whatever

        utilityInterface.specificBehavior( null );

        // perform work with args or whatever
    }

}
```